# I want to run a cron in node js to add youtube video data in Neo4j DB but I have an error when the cron runs

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cron

app.js

```
var express           =     require('express')
  , neo4j_match               =     require('neo4j')
   , session           =     require('express-session')
  , bodyParser        =     require('body-parser')
  , moment            =     require('moment')
  , request           =     require('request')
  , app               =     express();
  var every = require('every-moment');
  var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  var db = new neo4j_match.GraphDatabase('http://Novasys:1234567@localhost:7474');
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("Novasys", "1234567"));
var session = driver.session();
  every(40, 'seconds', function() {

session
  .run('match (c:channel) where c.from="yt" return c')
  .then(function(result){
    return result.records.map(function(record){
      return {
        title: record._fields[0].properties.channelid
      };
    })
    session.close();
  })
  .then(function(cron_channel){
    for (var k in cron_channel){
       (function(k){
          console.log(cron_channel[k].title);
          request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId='+cron_channel[k].title+'&order=date&key=AIzaSyBj7mztzfuZq_LA_5TYHLAw-Qaa2Fof3JU', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  body=JSON.parse(body);

  for(var i in body.items){
    (function(i){
    //selecting video id and getting their meta data
    request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics,snippet,contentDetails&id='+body.items[i].id.videoId+'&key=AIzaSyBj7mztzfuZq_LA_5TYHLAw-Qaa2Fof3JU',function(err, res, vid){
    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200){
    vid=JSON.parse(vid);
    for(var j in vid.items){
        (function(j){
      //node creation 
      if(vid.items[j].statistics.likeCount == null){
        db.cypher({
    query: 'match (a:channel) where a.channelid={channelParam} merge (n:video {id:{idParam}, categoryid:{categoryidParam}, title:{titleParam}, description:{descriptionParam}, created_time:{created_timeParam},category:a.category, source:{channelParam}, length:{lengthParam}, video_thumbnail:{video_thumbnailParam}, from:"yt"}) ON CREATE SET n.language=a.language, n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam}, n.android_views=0, n.android_likes=0, n.created_at=timestamp() ON MATCH SET n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam} RETURN n',
params: {
        idParam:vid.items[j].id,
        titleParam:vid.items[j].snippet.title, 
        categoryidParam:vid.items[j].snippet.categoryId,
        descriptionParam:vid.items[j].snippet.description,
        created_timeParam:vid.items[j].snippet.publishedAt, 
        channelParam:cron_channel[k].title, 
        lengthParam:moment.duration(vid.items[j].contentDetails.duration).asMilliseconds(),
        viewCountParam:vid.items[j].statistics.viewCount,
        likeCountParam:0, 
        video_thumbnailParam:vid.items[j].snippet.thumbnails.high.url
},
},
function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var result = results[0];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found.');
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }

});
      }
      else if(vid.items[j].statistics.viewCount == null){
           db.cypher({
    query: 'match (c:channel), (v:video), (u:user) where (v.source=c.channelid OR v.source=c.title) AND c.channelid={channel_id} AND u.title={userid} optional match (u:user)-[r:like]-(v) optional match (u:user)-[re:repick]-(v) RETURN v.title,v.id, v.created_time,v.likes,v.views,v.android_likes, v.android_views,v.from,c.title, c.channelid,c.channelthumbnail,c.followers, c.video_count,r.title ,re.title ORDER BY v.created_time LIMIT 200',
params: {
        idParam:vid.items[j].id,
        titleParam:vid.items[j].snippet.title,
        descriptionParam:vid.items[j].snippet.description, 
        categoryidParam:vid.items[j].snippet.categoryId,
        created_timeParam:vid.items[j].snippet.publishedAt,
        channelParam:cron_channel[k].title, 
        lengthParam:moment.duration(vid.items[j].contentDetails.duration).asMilliseconds(),
        viewCountParam:0,
        likeCountParam:vid.items[j].statistics.likeCount, 
        video_thumbnailParam:vid.items[j].snippet.thumbnails.high.url
},
},
function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var result = results[0];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found.');
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
      }
      else if(vid.items[j].statistics.viewCount == null && vid.items[j].statistics.likeCount == null){

db.cypher({
    query: 'match (a:channel) where a.channelid={channelParam} merge (n:video {id:{idParam}, categoryid:{categoryidParam}, title:{titleParam}, description:{descriptionParam}, created_time:{created_timeParam},category:a.category, source:{channelParam}, length:{lengthParam}, video_thumbnail:{video_thumbnailParam}, from:"yt"}) ON CREATE SET n.language=a.language, n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam}, n.android_views=0, n.android_likes=0, n.created_at=timestamp() ON MATCH SET n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam} RETURN n',
params: {
        idParam:vid.items[j].id,
        titleParam:vid.items[j].snippet.title,
        descriptionParam:vid.items[j].snippet.description, 
        categoryidParam:vid.items[j].snippet.categoryId,
        created_timeParam:vid.items[j].snippet.publishedAt, 
        channelParam:cron_channel[k].title, 
        lengthParam:moment.duration(vid.items[j].contentDetails.duration).asMilliseconds(),
        viewCountParam:0, 
        likeCountParam:0, 
        video_thumbnailParam:vid.items[j].snippet.thumbnails.high.url
},
},
function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var result = results[0];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found.');
    } else {
         console.log("success");
    }
});

      }
      else{
      db.cypher({
    query: 'match (a:channel) where a.channelid={channelParam} merge (n:video {id:{idParam}, title:{titleParam}, categoryid:{categoryidParam}, description:{descriptionParam}, created_time:{created_timeParam},category:a.category, source:{channelParam}, length:{lengthParam}, video_thumbnail:{video_thumbnailParam}, from:"yt"}) ON CREATE SET n.language=a.language, n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam}, n.android_views=0, n.android_likes=0, n.created_at=timestamp() ON MATCH SET n.views={viewCountParam}, n.likes={likeCountParam} RETURN n',
params: {
        idParam:vid.items[j].id,
        titleParam:vid.items[j].snippet.title,
        descriptionParam:vid.items[j].snippet.description, 
        categoryidParam:vid.items[j].snippet.categoryId,
        created_timeParam:vid.items[j].snippet.publishedAt,
        channelParam:cron_channel[k].title, 
        lengthParam:moment.duration(vid.items[j].contentDetails.duration).asMilliseconds(),
        viewCountParam:vid.items[j].statistics.viewCount, 
        likeCountParam:vid.items[j].statistics.likeCount, 
        video_thumbnailParam:vid.items[j].snippet.thumbnails.high.url
},
},
function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var result = results[0];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found.');
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
}
  session
  .run('match (a:video), (b:language) where a.language=b.title merge (b)-[r:video_lang{title:"video_lang"}]-(a) return a,b,r ')
  .then(function(result){
    console.log("success1");
    session.close();
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });

  //relation creation
  session
  .run('match (a:channel), (b:video) where a.channelid={channelParam} AND b.source={channelParam} merge (a)-[r:rel_video{title:"yt"}]->(b) return a,b,r',{channelParam:cron_channel[k].title})
  .then(function(result){
    console.log("success2");
    session.close();
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
        })(j);
        }
                }
    })  
})(i);
}//first for
  }
})

       })(k);


}



  }); 
});
```

the server side error

```
{ Error: Connection was closed by server
    at Neo4jError.Error (native)
    at new Neo4jError (C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\Youtube Cron\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\error.js:76:132)
    at newError (C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\Youtube Cron\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\error.js:66:10)
    at NodeChannel._handleConnectionTerminated (C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\Youtube Cron\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\internal\ch-node.js:336:41)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ServiceUnavailable' }
```

Database log
debug.log

```
2017-05-18 16:09:16.849+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.SocketTransportHandler] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 922746887, max: 934281216) failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 922746887, max: 934281216)
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 922746887, max: 934281216)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:578)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:709)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:698)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:237)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:141)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:262)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:170)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:107)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.allocate(SslHandler.java:1472)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.allocateOutNetBuf(SslHandler.java:1482)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:519)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:490)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:779)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:39)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1148)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:454)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-05-18 16:09:16.937+0000 WARN  [io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext] Failed to mark a promise as failure because it has succeeded already: DefaultChannelPromise@3c0b7552(success)
```

Comment: @Clowin please *do not* spellcheck thank you notes but remove them instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove

Comment: Sure Alexei. I'll do that going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not a problem of memory, actually the error was generated by session because it was not closed properly.

Do the following to solve the issue.
1. the very first session is not closed properly, session.close() call goes after return. code could be changed to this:

```
session
  .run('match (c:channel) where c.from="yt" return c')
  .then(function (result) {
    session.close(); // <<-- session is closed here
    return result.records.map(function (record) {
      return {
        title: record._fields[0].properties.channelid
      };
    })
  })
...
```

2. sessions should not be reused after being closed. please add var session = driver.session() before two last session.run(...) calls. i.e. before:

   session.run('match (a:video), (b:language) where a.language=b.title merge (b)-[r:video_lang{title:"video_lang"}]-(a) return a,b,r')

and before:

```
session.run('match (a:channel), (b:video) where a.channelid={channelParam} AND b.source={channelParam} merge (a)-[r:rel_video{title:"yt"}]->(b) return a,b,r',{channelParam:cron_channel[k].title})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 922746887, max: 934281216)
```

You will need to increase your JVM memory limits, Or increase the RAM on your server.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, but are sure this problem is created by memory only.

Comment: It looks that way there is nothing else wrong in the logs that I can see

Comment: ok, then I will host my code and if again get any issue I will get back to you. Thanks